# IOS adaptive layout using Autolayout

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios-autolayout, adaptive-layout

I am working on IOS app and its my first app to be build on IOS. I have good experience of developing Android apps. So I have gathered basic information and knowledge about IOS development. I am working on autolayout. But I am not getting it work completely. I have seen Some developers are working on code, But I just want to use IB as I believe there will be some way to handle this.

So looking for help, Please do not down vote my this post As I am posting this after trying almost everything I get on internet.

First take a look at what I have developed and what it is :
[image]

in picture there are different numbers of simulator such as **Ipad pro 12.9, Ipone 8 plus and I phone se**

**What I have done so far:**

- I have taken the View (the white box in middle). I have made it center vertically and center horizontally.
- I have set view height as 300 points, and width to match the superview with some margins
- I have put the Text Fields for taking Phone and PIN from user and OK button as shown in picture.

**Problem & what I want:**
 - The problem is view is center vertical and horizontal but not its
   content are. I want this view to manage its height on the basis of
   its content inside. so that It can be looked as center aligned
   vertically. Right now its not center align vertically
 - Secondly the problem is the width of text fields, as on Ipad they looks too bad. So I really want them to be look good on all devices.

Is there any solution for this using the adaptive/Auto layout? please help me that How can I get this using IB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try following solution:-**

1. Fix the width of textfield.
2. For label use minimum font scale(search on google).
3. For width and height you have to use adaptive layout.

**width** = 70% of superview which means multiplier for your view will be 0.7

**height** = 60% of superview which means multiplier for your view will be 0.6

Refer to the image:-

**Equal width with the superview**

[image: Equal width with the superview]

**Set the multiplier as 0.7**

[image: Set the multiplier as 0.7]

Comment: isnt there work around that give me weapping the content in height prespective. Because giving 50% of height is fine but not reallt working

Comment: because u are providing height twice(300points as u mentioned).

Comment: So basically over constraints will result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: no as you guide me, I am now not giving the height explicitly. I have made multiplier to 0.50, but I want it to wrap it content

Comment: you gave me idea, I was trying from last 5 days, thanks to you

Answer (score 3):

@Android Teem,
For this you need to use `SizeClasses` along with the `AutoLayout`.

Below I am trying to give you solution.

use items structure as like below. Don't use another `UIView` inside main view. Instead user `StackView`. It automatically adjust contents inside it. For more just look for "`UIStackView`" on [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview).

[image]

Next you need to add constraints to stack view as

- Leading 10 (for x)
- Trailing 10 (for y)
- Allign to center (for width)

height stack view will automatically adjust.

Now double click on leading and trailing constraint will open size attributes. Click on "+" icon just before `Constant`. It will show you a pop up. add `Regular Width Regular Height` for iPad and set values as 200 (I have give 200, you can give based on your calculation and requirement). this will show like below image

[image]

Now Either run or check from preview for all screens. you will get desired results. my changes show result as below

[image]

**Happy Coding**

Comment: @android teem please do acknowledge if solution worked or you still face any issue

Comment: Chaursaia Your solution is more compact and helping. I am now trying it. but I have already selected the proposed solution. because he replied me first :(

Comment: np android teem. most important is, it helped you. :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do. Go to the storyboard

> 1. Right click on the white area of the screen and drag the cursor to the green area.
>
>    2. Few options will appear, select Equal Heights
>    3. Now the white dialog box will become equal height to the green screen but don't worry. Select that height constraint and set the
>         multiplier to let's say 0.5 for 50% height of super view. Repeat the
>         same for width

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height constraint and hook the bottom most button to the bottom of the view

Comment: what do you mean by this? and what about width of text fields

Comment: don't change width of the white view , hook all components correctly from top to bottom and you will get no white space in the bottom

Comment: regarding with of the white view control drag from it to it;s superView , select Equal-widths and click the constraint then change it's multiplier say by 0.5